# How to manipulate an array inside in activerecord in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, parameters

I am working in this case. A client can have `N` quantity of tariffs, I need to save all.

In my `ClientController` it is working like this:

```
  def new
    @Client = Client.new()

    4.times do
      tariffs = @Client.tariffs.build
    end
  end
```

Now from the view "register clients"  I received the `params` like this:

```
 "client"=>{"name"=>"",
 "gender"=>[""],
 "hair_color_id"=>"",
 "age"=>"",
 "height"=>"",
 "Weight"=>"",
 "orientation"=>"",
 "country_id"=>"",
 "Language"=>[""],
 "service"=>[""],
 "category_id"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "tariffs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "1"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "2"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "3"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "4"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "5"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "6"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"},
 "7"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "duration"=>"Hours",
 "price"=>"",
 "currency_id"=>"1"}},
 "homeshow"=>"0",
 "planetariff"=>"0",
 "profileclient"=>"0",
 "city_id"=>"",
 "phonenumber"=>"",
 "fullname"=>"",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"123@example.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}},
 "commit"=>"Register",
 "locale"=>"en"}
```

I want to access the array "tariffs_attributes" and save the content there.

I tried with this line inside `def create`

```
 @tariffs = Tariff.create(params[:tariffs_attributes])
```

but I need to update/add the id of the client to each register, like this:

```
if @client.save

  @tariffs.each do|l|
    @tariff = l
    @tariff.update_attribute(:client_id, @client_id )
    @tariff.save
end
```

I tried with:

```
params[:client][tariffs_attributes].each do |l|
       @tariff = Tariff.new(l)
       @tariff.update_attribute(:client_id, @client_id) 
       @tariff.save
end
```

Any ideas or suggestion?? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to create the tarrifs when the client registration is initialized , not when the client is registered? I can't really grasp what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
   params["client"]["tariffs_attributes"].each do |client_id, tariff_attributes|
      @tariff = Tariff.new(tariff_attributes)
      @tariff.update_attribute(:client_id, client_id)
      @tariff.save
    end
```

Here, you are looping through all the `tariffs_attributes` which is a hash having `key` as the `client_id` and value is the `tariff_attributes`.

Also, looking at your `params` hash, all of its `keys` and `values` are strings NOT symbols. So, you have to do: `params["client"]["tariffs_attributes"]` to grab all the `tariffs_attributes` from the `params` hash. If you use, symbol `:client`, like this: `params[:client][:tariffs_attributes]`, it won't work and will get nothing/nil.